# Hiding navigation bar without rooting on android

Tags: android, navigationbar, android-fullscreen

I want to make fullscreen application for android tablets and i try to hide navigation bar and for 4.0+. I read similar questions and answers to it but what i found are dont work for me. If it is not possible to hide navigation bar forever, how can i hide it and after make it visible with slide from bottom? I saw in some games and i think this is possible. So far i tried this and at first it hides navigation bar but when i touched the screen navigation bar become visible again and i dont want it.

```
decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

and i also tried this but again doest work for me

```
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
            (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
            // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
          decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


            } else {
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
          decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
            }
        }
    });
```

How can i hide it and make it visible with sliding from bottom or hide forever? 
Please give me an advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this is more of a suggestion than an answer, here goes an idea: Have you tried to completely remove the ActionBar? If you do that, you can add in a pseudo-ActionBar whenever you want (and animate it however as well). The issue just resides in adding all the ActionBar features and managing it yourself- including icon, up button, title, buttons, etc. If you still have trouble **removing** it completely, feel free to let me know. I also asked a similar question on removing the ActionBar, so that should help as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If i remove ActionBar, will bottom navigation bar be invisible? If so, how can i remove actionbar?

Comment: Sorry for being a bit late in replying, but it depends on what you mean by "bottom navigation bar". If you mean navigation selections along the bottom edge of the screen, that's separate from the ActionBar. If you want to remove the ActionBar **completely** and **utterly** (which I had to for full control and customizability for a client's app), then just read the amazing answer here by TulsiramRathod: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901444/removing-extra-space-in-custom-actionbar]. Note that this **doesn't** limit you to API 4.0/4.4+. If you want, I can write a sort of answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are describing that you have seen in some games is called "Immersive Mode".  The navigation bar disappears completely, and a gesture from the edge of the screen brings it back.  This feature is available starting at Android version 4.4.

Before Android 4.4, since Android version 4.0, you can use the "Hide Navigation" flag, which will temporarily hide the navigation bar.  The problem with this mode is that any interaction with the screen will cause the navigation bar to reappear.  This of course isn't very useful for apps that require a lot of interaction with the screen, like most games.

I typically use the following functions for moving in and out of immersive mode:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE); // This flag only for 4.4+
}

private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Then in my onCreate, I set mDecorView and call hideSystemUI:

```
    mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    hideSystemUI();
```

The code is similar to what you have though, so this may not help.  There is a detailed video on the subject, including much more detailed source code examples, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am testing on android 4.2.2 device. That's why i cannot use immersive mode and so far i could not find anything useful.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem with my game.  Best you can do prior to 4.4 is the low profile flag.  Buttons are still there and using up space, but as faint dots.  In my case, I hid everything and went into low profile.  User presses "Back" to toggle between low profile and normal with menus visible.  The hide navigation flag is useless if your app requires constant screen interaction.